# how to get list of all users with role equal None

Tags: wordpress

I use code below and it return 0 result

```
$args = array(
    'role'    => 'None',
    'orderby' => 'last_name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);
$users = get_users( $args );
```

and if I change role to '' or NULL it return all user

```
$args = array(
    'role'    => '',
    'orderby' => 'last_name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);
$users = get_users( $args );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard vanilla WordPress there is no role by the name of "none".

So you need to get it using pass '' NULL.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
If it can't filter by "none" I think I need to find another solution.